# RaphaelJS: draw a path over another SVG element

Tags: javascript, raphael

I have a 500x400px container, where I'm working with RaphaelJS to manage some SVG goodies. I've loaded an image with this code:

```
var img = paper.image("images/image.jpg", 50, 200, 90, 110);
```

Now I want to draw a path relative to this element. How should I do?
If I write something like:

```
var c = paper.path("M 18.00,79.75 C 18.00,79.50 52.50,79.75 52.50,79.75...");
```

The path is being created relative to the parent container, and doesn't take the proper position over my image.
Thanks for your support

--- edit ----

This is my dashboard with its styling:

```
#canvas {
        float: left;
        width: 500px;
        height: 400px;
        border: 1px solid #333;
}

<div id="canvas"></div>
```

And this is part of the javascript code:

```
// Creates canvas 500 × 400 inside canvas div
var paper = Raphael(document.getElementById('canvas'), 500, 400);
// Load an image at 50, 200
var img = paper.image("images/image.jpg", 50, 200, 90, 110);
```

After that, I would like to fill an SVG path, positioning it over my image.
If I write something like:

```
var c = paper.path("M 18.00,79.75 C 18.00,79.50 52.50,79.75 52.50,79.75...");
```

This path is created upon the #canvas container, starting from 0,0 coords.
How do I do?

Comment: It would be best if you could provide more of your code so that we can actually see what your whole approach looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Please look into this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/XRBRz/. In this fiddle, imagine the black rectangle as your image.
The staircase path is drawn relative to the black rectangle, by translating the path to the origin of the rectangle.
Also the path(staircase) is given a clip-path having the same dimension of the black rectangle, to clip the path outside the black rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are thinking that Raphael keeps a reference to a current pen position between creation of shapes, etc. I don't think this is true... I believe that when you add a path, the starting position of that path is relative to the canvas 0,0. (Note that the path `'M'` command does allow a relative moveTo `'m'`, but I think this only works after the initial one in a path string... at the beginning, it seems to be absolute, regardless of case)

So, if you want to start the path from the top left corner of the image, start the path string with `"M50,200"` - for bottom right, start it with `"M140,310"`.

If you want the path to **stay** attached to the image at that point, add them to a set. But that is another post... :-)